# Creating a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

Currently I have a view that joins multiple tables together, the tables are set up in the following way:

```
ACCOUNTS (id, first_name, last_name, etc.)

CONTACTS (id, name, etc.)

ACCOUNT_CONTACTS (id, account_id, contact_id)

EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL (id, bean_id (same as account_id / contact_id), email_address_id)

EMAIL_ADDRESSES (email_address_id, email_address)
```

However I have two tables that I join together which can have multiple emails associated with one id, here is an example of the structure:

Table: EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL

```
id       email_address_id     bean_id
1          2d5b8               61720
2          14355b              61720
```

Table: EMAIL_ADDRESSES

```
id         email_address
2db58      WalterWhite@gmail.com
14355b     WW@gmail.com
```

When creating my view I want to be able to retrieve these multiple emails associated to one user. Currently this is my code for the view, which only retrieves one email:

```
SELECT AC.id, A.id AS account_id, A.name, A.description, A.industry, A.phone_fax, A.phone_office, A.shipping_address_street, A.shipping_address_city, A.shipping_address_state, A.shipping_address_postalcode, A.shipping_address_country, C.id AS contact_id, C.first_name, C.last_name, C.title, C.department, C.phone_home, C.phone_mobile, C.phone_work, C.primary_address_street, C.primary_address_city, C.primary_address_state, C.primary_address_postalcode, C.primary_address_country, EA.email_address, EA_C.email_address as email_contact
FROM ACCOUNTS A 
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS_CONTACTS AS AC ON A.id = AC.account_id 
INNER JOIN CONTACTS AS C ON C.id = AC.contact_id 
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER ON ER.bean_id = A.id 
AND ER.bean_module = "Accounts"
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER_C ON ER_C.bean_id = C.id 
AND ER_C.bean_module = "Contacts"
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA ON ER.email_address_id = EA.id
LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA_C ON ER_C.email_address_id = EA_C.id
```

This query will return two rows associated with the same user, have the exact same information except for the email address, I would like to have the second email address (or additional emails) added to the the same row and not have additional rows created.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ... GROUP_CONCAT(email_address) ... 
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY A.id;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jatin : Yes it does.  The question was "I would like to have the second email address (or additional emails) added to the the same row and not have additional rows created. "  Short of writing all the code for him, this provides the one missing clue -- `GROUP_CONCAT` plus `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @RickJames thank you this works wonderfully, however I want each email to be in a separate column. So for example: email_1: abc@gmail.com, email_2: efg@gmail.com, email_3: hij@gmail.com, etc.. This puts all the emails in one column separated by a comma.

Comment: The comma can be any string `GROUP_CONCAT( ... SEPARATOR '...' )`.  But to get separate columns -- this is better done with application code.

Comment: @RickJames I can't use the method suggested here? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279781/mysql-group-concat-with-column-split

Comment: @RickJames I agree! However I can't use php to separate the columns :S I am using VB6 .

Comment: Surely VB has sufficient tools for such.